# Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: php, class

Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

```
        else if($main->parms('page') == 'poll' && !empty($main->parms_page()))
```

Comment: we would need to see more of the code to examine the issue. esp. parms and parms_page functions.

Answer (score 1):

Problem may be this: `!empty($main->parms_page())`

You can use a variable and use it inside the if statement,

```
$check = !empty($main->parms_page());
```

Then

```
else if($main->parms('page') == 'poll' && !empty($check))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `PHP 5.5`, `empty()` only supports variables, anything else will result in a parse error.

In other words, the following will not work: `!empty($main->parms_page())`.

```
$var = $main->parms_page();
else if($main->parms('page') == 'poll' && !empty($var))
```

[See empty() supports arbitrary expressions](http://pk1.php.net/migration55.new-features)